# Delete unused tables from the drupal database

Tags: entities, database

In my Drupal database I have so many field_deleted_data_XX and field_deleted_revision_XX tables. I have disable the revision entity but I want to delete these existing revision created tables, can I delete these tables directly or Is there any SQL script to delete unused tables from the database.

Comment: Just run cron a few times

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can safely remove them yes. You can use drush to delete these tables: run `drush eval 'field_delete_field("yourfield")'` and run cron afterwards with `drush cron`.

Comment: OK thanks I will try using drush but how to run using cron? can you give some example.

Comment: `drush cr` is a rebuild (`drupal_flush_all_caches` plus some D8 specific things related to the autoloader), `drush cron` runs cron.

Comment: Also the run cron option from the system status report page will do it.